# How can I retrieve all action names which are in tests from HP ALM?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, alm, hp-alm

In HP ALM there are many test cases.Inside test cases there are many actions.I want to retrieve all the action names from that test cases.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches, but in all cases you need to get familiar with the(COM) Automation associated with HPE(Microfocus) tools

**Approach 1)**
Download the Test Case to the FileSystem using the `OTA API` (HPE ALM Automation); and then traverse the folder structure on your filesystem and look for folders with ActionX names. These are all actions found in the test case(except Action 0 - which is the Test Case or entry point). The name of each action however is binary encoded in one of the files inside the Action folder - (I don't remember exactly which one) so do this only as personal fun, as binary data structures are kinda hard to decode.

**Approach 2**
Use `Quicktest.Application` Automation Object and not (only) the HPE ALM one. Start a QTP Application, connect to ALM, open the test case and voila the Automation Object gives you the actions, their names params etc. [More info in the Offical Doc](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/all/AutomationObjectModel/Default.htm#QuickTest~Action.html%3FTocPath%3DAction%2520Object%7C_____0)

Of course you can combine the 2 objects. Use the OTA API to look up and search Tests in HPE ALM and the Quicktest(UFT) Automation Object to get info about tests(Or even modify them - modify and save does the trick)